If you switch to a non-orthogonal basis, are vectors that were previously orthogonal still orthogonal?
I am pretty new to linear algebra. If you have a set of vectors that are orthogonal in one basis, and you switch to a different basis (say, a non-orthogonal one), would the vectors there still be orthogonal? I can infer that geometrically they wouldn't have a 90$^\circ$ angle between them, but algebraically would the dot product still be 0? Or, could you pick the basis for them that they stay orthogonal?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are an orthogonal basis.  $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ are a non-orthogonal basis.  In the non-orthogonal basis, $(1,0)$ is $(1,-1)$ and $(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$.

"I can infer that geometrically they wouldn't have a 90$^\circ$ angle between them..." suggests to me you might be confusing vectors with their representations relative to a given basis, especially if you're working entirely in a vector space like $\mathbb{R}^n$. When you change basis, you're not changing anything about the geometry of the original vectors, you're just changing their representations (coordinates). Orthogonality is a geometrical property of the vectors. See here for more on this.

@blargoner - "suggests to me you might be confusing vectors with their representations relative to a given basis" - that's assuming a specific point of view where vectors are objects that exist out there and have coordinate representation. Useful in many application, but not fundamental to the notion of vector spaces; one does not need to take that view. You can also just think about a linear map from one vector space to a different one, without any "extra" ideas on top of that

To say that a set of vectors $S$ in a vector space $V$ is orthogonal means that $V$ must be an inner product space—that is, $V$ carries a symmetric, positive-definite bilinear form $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, and that if $s_1, s_2 \in S$ then $\langle s_1, s_2 \rangle = 0$ whenever $s_1 \neq s_2$. The property of orthogonality does not depend on the choice of any basis.
Some confusion may arise concerning the inner product and its connection to the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with a basis $B = \{u_1, \ldots, u_m\}$, then the choice of $B$ defines an isomorphism $\phi_B \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to V$, where $\phi_B(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i u_i$ for a vector $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
If $V$ has an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, then we can "pull back" that inner product using $\phi_B$ to obtain an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^m$, where the pullback is defined by
$$
\langle x, y \rangle_{\phi_B} := \langle \phi_B(x), \phi_B(y) \rangle \quad \text{for } x, y \in \mathbb{R}^m.
$$
If the basis $B$ that we chose is an orthonormal basis, then $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\phi_B}$ is the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Thus, if you have an orthonormal set $S$ in a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$, and you pick an orthonormal basis $B$ of $V$, then the set of coordinate vectors for the elements of $S$, that is, the set $\phi_B^{-1}(S)$, will consist of vectors that are pairwise orthogonal with respect to the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^m$.
